# overridden method does not throw Exception Java

Tags: java, sqlite

estoy practicando el uso de las interfaces en java, pero tengo unos problemas a la hora de compilar mi codigo. Mirad os lo enseño:

```
./Jbdc.java:18: error: introducir() in Jbdc cannot implement introducir()  in InterfazBD
public void introducir() throws Exception

overridden method does not throw Exception
 1 error
```

Estoy aprendiendo y no tengo mucha idea de como solucionarlo, ¿me podeis hechar una mano?

```
 (Principal)
public class App{

public static void main(String arg[]){

    JsonRead json = new JsonRead();
    Jbdc sqlite = new Jbdc();
    grabarJson(json);
    introducirSQL(sqlite);
}

    public static void grabarJson(InterfazGrabar fichero){
    fichero.grabar();
    }

    public static void grabarTxt(InterfazGrabar fichero){
    fichero.grabar();
    }

    public static void introducirSQL(InterfazBD fichero){
    fichero.introducir();
    }
}
```

y el fichero Jbdc

```
 Jbdc (this file enter the data in a database)

public class Jbdc implements InterfazBD{

private static final String URL = "jdbc:sqlite:test.db";
    public void introducir() throws Exception{
        createDb();
        createTable();
        Aula a = null;
        int contador = 0;
        try {
            FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("aula.dat");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);
            while (inFile.available()>0) {
                a = (Aula)in.readObject();
                String materiaslista ="";
                String nombre = a.getNombre();
                String grupo = a.getGrupo();
                int tutor= a.getTutor();
                ArrayList<String> materias = a.getMaterias();
                for (int counter = 0; counter < materias.size(); counter++) {             
                    materiaslista = materiaslista + materias.get(counter) + ",";
                }
                insertDatos(nombre,grupo,tutor,materiaslista);
            }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("ERROR");
    }
        System.out.println("¡Listo!");
    }

    private static void insertDatos(String nombre,String grupo, int tutor,String materiaslista) {
        final String SQL = "INSERT INTO datos VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        try (Connection con = getConnection(); PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL);) {
            ps.setString(1, nombre); 
            ps.setString(2, grupo);
            ps.setInt(3, tutor);
            ps.setString(4, materiaslista); 
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createTable() {
        final String SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datos (nombre TEXT,grupo TEXT, tutor INTEGER, materiaslista TEXT);";
        // This SQL Query is not "dynamic". Columns are static, so no need to use
        // PreparedStatement.
        try (Connection con = getConnection(); Statement statement = con.createStatement();) {
            statement.executeUpdate(SQL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createDb() {
        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.getMetaData();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
    }
}
```

InterfazBD.java

```
public interface InterfazBD{

    public void introducir();

}
```

Comment: Falta la declaración de la interfaz, que es donde está el problema

Comment: Ya la tengo declarada y en el mismo directorio. Adjunto el codigo mismo arriba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en tu método `introducir()` en tu interface, le estas diciendo que tu metodo lanzara una excepción pero nunca la lanzas, eso le dice al compilador que cualquier método que trate de llame a este método deberá de controlar la excepción que este método posiblemente lanzara (ya sea usando un bloque try-catch...) pero lo que haces en tu método es cachar la excepción ahi mismo lo cual no tiene sentido. Puedes hacer dos cosas elimina el `throws Exception` o lanza la excepcion que quieres cachar.

```
//Eliminando Trows

public void introducir(){
        createDb();
        createTable();
        Aula a = null;
        int contador = 0;
        try {
            FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("aula.dat");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);
            while (inFile.available()>0) {
                a = (Aula)in.readObject();
                String materiaslista ="";
                String nombre = a.getNombre();
                String grupo = a.getGrupo();
                int tutor= a.getTutor();
                ArrayList<String> materias = a.getMaterias();
                for (int counter = 0; counter < materias.size(); counter++) {             
                    materiaslista = materiaslista + materias.get(counter) + ",";
                }
                insertDatos(nombre,grupo,tutor,materiaslista);
            }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("ERROR");
    }
        System.out.println("¡Listo!");
    }

//Agregando la excepcion
public void introducir() throws Exception{
        createDb();
        createTable();
        Aula a = null;
        int contador = 0;
        try {
            FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("aula.dat");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);
            while (inFile.available()>0) {
                a = (Aula)in.readObject();
                String materiaslista ="";
                String nombre = a.getNombre();
                String grupo = a.getGrupo();
                int tutor= a.getTutor();
                ArrayList<String> materias = a.getMaterias();
                for (int counter = 0; counter < materias.size(); counter++) {             
                    materiaslista = materiaslista + materias.get(counter) + ",";
                }
                insertDatos(nombre,grupo,tutor,materiaslista);
            }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("ERROR");
        throw e;
    }
        System.out.println("¡Listo!");
    }
```

Si lanzas la excepcion deberas cacharla cuando llames al metodo:

```
public static void introducirSQL(InterfazBD fichero){
    try{
    fichero.introducir();
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
    }
```

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias compañero!